# SQL: How can I select the first and last date for each customer?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I can't seem to figure this one out. I have a table of transactions (lots of them), with date, customer ID etc.

I want to select, for a specific day, the datetime for only the first AND the last transaction for each customer on that day, like so:

```
custID FirstT  LastT
318    08:05   18:35
968    03:21   13:54
488    12:34   14:28
```

SQL Server 2008. Sounds simple enough but I'm about ready to throw in the towel... Would appreciate help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  custID,
  MIN(transaction_date)  AS FirstT,
  MAX(transaction_date)  AS LastT
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      transaction_date >= '2014-04-01'
  AND transaction_date <  '2014-04-02'
GROUP BY
  custID
```

Comment: That's... so simple I feel stupid now... :) Thank you!! And I think I finally understand the group by clause...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT custid, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date)) Date, MIN(date) FirstT, MAX(date) LastT
FROM transactions
GROUP BY custid, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your schema but you should be doing something like this:

```
    select custID, max(transactionDate), min(transactionDate)
where cast(transactionDate as date) = '20140101'
    group by custID
```

Comment: As far as I am aware; `where cast(transactionDate as date) = '20140101'` will prevent any use of an index on `transactionDate`.

Comment: `cast(transactionDate as date)` is not equal to '20140101'`

Comment: @MatBailie - I've been pulled up on this by some experts before. In fact, the cast to date *doesn't* prevent the use of the index. There's logic in there to recognise this situation. See [What is the most efficient way to trim time from datetime](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Thanks for that, useful to know.  There was already enough doubt in my mind for me to prefix it with `As far as I am aware;` :)  I think I'll stick with `>= AND <` though, now I just need to wonder if I'm justified in doing so.

Comment: @MatBailie - was just editing my previous comment to include link to Article by Aaron Bertrand

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT custID, transaction_date FROM transactions ORDER BY transaction_date LIMIT 1) t
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT custID, transaction_date FROM transactions ORDER BY transaction_date DESC LIMIT 1) t1
```